# How to open Duplo train base 2961b?

Tags: duplo, repair, disassembly

How can I open a Duplo train base 2961b without destroying it? It is not working despite fresh batteries. There are no screws.

[image: Train base 2951]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This part wasn't meant to be taken apart,
but it is possible.

[image]

[image]

[Source with more text and images](https://www.cailliau.org/Alphabetical/L/Lego/Duplo/Train/Locomotives/)

also this (very dark) [video tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pJnAzFLisDg&t=0s)

and another [video tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=n64Qf7xkqWA)

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I managed to open the train base using the poorly illuminated video tutorial and three kitchen knives. It is surely the easiest, but also most dangerous way to do so. The train did not work because of a loose contact to the motor.